# Multilayer/deep recurrent layer

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, lstm, rnn

I might be missing something, but I'm completely unable to find any reference about this topic.

In the literature, there are many references about RNN, GRU, LSTM, STAR and many other architecture that exploits some sort of trick to avoid having vanishing gradient and stable learning.

However, to me seems that there is no work about actually improving how much a RNN can "save" inside the recurrent state.

From this my question: why don't we use *deep recurrent layers* in order to enable our model to better encode the recurrent state?

[image]

In my opinion, this is neither equivalent to stacking multiple RNN nor using `MultiRNNCell` from tensorflow

Anybody has any reference to some paper about this? i tried to search for "deep recurrent layer" or "multilayer FFN in recurrent layer" but I was not able to find anything

Comment: This paper explains how deep RNN memory works: Does it help? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00748.pdf

Comment: @NicolasMartin nice paper, but there you have stacked RNN, not one single deep recurrent layer